# what heap pop returns?

Tags: python, heapq

I am confused in heap pop output.

```py
import heapq
heapq.heappush(PQ, ['b', 0.95])
heapq.heappush(PQ, ['d', 0.72])
heapq.heappush(PQ, ['e', 1.75])

a = heapq.heappop(PQ)
print (a)
```

It returns : ['b', 0.95]
Why it's not returning ['d', 0.72]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import heapq
PQ = []
heapq.heappush(PQ, ['z', 0.95]) # Changed it to z which is bigger 
heapq.heappush(PQ, ['d', 0.72])
heapq.heappush(PQ, ['e', 1.75])

a = heapq.heappop(PQ)
print (a)
```

The result is ['d', 0.72]. The first element is used to sort min-heap.